# What happened to the user reemrevnivek?

Tags: discussion, moderation, user-accounts

There once was a user named reemrevnivek.  He had been here since the Chiphacker days.  In fact, he was recently elected moderator.  Few people could understand the meaning behind his username.  Legend says it was crafted on a site long ago where ordinary names were unavailable, and that you can read it by turning your computer upside down and crossing your eyes.

However, I can't find him anymore.  Where did he go?  Why can't I summon him with @reemrevnivek anymore?

Answer (score 10):

He was a smelly dude with an attitude. You can't @reem him anymore because the almighty sucked him up in a great puff of wind last weekend, and he is no more. And there was partying everywhere. And joy.

And joy.

[image]

Glad I could clear that up.

Answer (score 4):

Yes... That's what they used to call me. reemrevnivek. That was my name. I am Kevin Vermeer. And I come back to you now at the turn of the tide.

Comment: Much better to pronounce.

Comment: @Daniel, speak english like I do, make it up as you go along

Comment: Lies! Stop trying to take the identity of the mod we just elected

Comment: "Kevin" - yeah, like *that's* a real name.